# Tikz: Math with coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, fp

I need to extract the coordinates of a node into a variable. I've tried `\pgfextractx`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
     \usepackage{fp}
     \usepackage{tikz}
     \usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \node (node1) at (0,0) {N1};
     \node (node2) at (2,0) {N2};
     \newdimen\varAX
     \pgfextractx{\varAX}{node1.center}
     \newdimen\varBX
     \pgfextractx{\varBX}{node2.center}
     \FPeval\varCX {clip(\varBX - \varAX)}
     \node at (\varCX,0) {N3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But it looks like FP can't work with lenghts (pt, cm, etc.), which I guess is logical looking back at it...

Also, when removed the FP and changed the third node to `\node at (\varBX,0) {N3};` it had a weird offset to the left. Even though it should have been overlapping the N2.

[image]

**EDIT**

After I posted this question, I noticed that you can't actually do something like `Node1.east` with the `pgfextract`. Which is a part of the final code. So I need a whole new solution of getting the X values as shown above ^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's

```
\pgfpointanchor{<point>}{<anchor>}
```

which you can use as

```
\pgfextractx{\centerAx}{\pgfpointanchor{node1}{center}}
```

A complete example placing N3 in the midpoint between N1 and N2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newdimen\centerAx
\newdimen\centerAy
\newdimen\centerBx
\newdimen\centerBy

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (node1) at (0,0) {N1};
\node (node2) at (2,0) {N2};
\pgfextractx{\centerAx}{\pgfpointanchor{node1}{center}}
\pgfextracty{\centerAy}{\pgfpointanchor{node1}{center}}
\pgfextractx{\centerBx}{\pgfpointanchor{node2}{center}}
\pgfextracty{\centerBy}{\pgfpointanchor{node2}{center}}
\node at (0.5\centerAx+0.5\centerBx,0) {N3};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, exactly what I needed. I did all the calculations in the node though, not the prettiest thing, but works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `let` syntax from `calc` library of TikZ

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \node (node1) at (0,0) {N1};
     \node (node2) at (2,0) {N2};
     \path let \p1=($(node2.west)-(node1.east)$) in node at (\x1,0) {N3};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. That is true, but I'm trying to find another solution because this way, the code will look really messy. I need to use these coordinates in 2 separate `for` loops and create more variables with them. Here is the full non-working code, I hope you can understand it. http://pastebin.com/bXHEbhru

Comment: @Areuz Find the x's and record them in your variables instead. I have a single line instead of your six lines. That cannot be messy